# Using QGIS Python interpreter outside QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, pyproj

I'm writing a simple Python Geoprocessing script which leverages two specific modules:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import pyproj
```

The script must be shared with colleagues in my organisation.To avoid hooking them up with a new Python installation, I intend to leverage the QGIS python interpreter which has these two modules by default (using QGIS 3.4.3 Madeira on W10). See image below:

[image]

I'm having difficulties finding and using QGIS's Python interpreter from which my colleagues could run my script. Firstly, the normal method for identifying the interpreter doesn't point to a Python interpeter but to qgis-bin.exe instead:

[image]

Secondly, the most obvious candidate for the Python interpeter (located at `c:\program files\qgis3.4\apps\Python37\python.exe`) doesn't recognize the same modules:

[image]

**To summarize**: using Python *from within* QGIS provides the right modules, but using the (presumably) same Python interpreter *outside* QGIS fails to import the same modules. How can this be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the environment variables to run the QGIS python outside.

In this case my QGIS installation is in **D:\QGIS**, so you should only change **OSGEO4W_ROOT**.

```
@ECHO OFF 

set OSGEO4W_ROOT=D:\QGIS

call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat"

path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis

set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES

set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins

set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages;%PYTHONPATH%

set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\plugins\platforms
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis


cd /d %~dp0

call cmd
```

and in the console you can import modules now.

[image]

Comment: That works, thanks, even though I don't fully grasp what's happening.

Comment: "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat" doesent exist in latest version of QGIS

Answer (score 1):

Could you try something like this for python file?

```
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\python.exe c:/Users/user/Desktop/xx/run.py
```

Comment: You can get DOS Path with `for %I in (.) do echo %~sI`
FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051088/get-dos-path-instead-of-windows-path