# How can I import pyqgis API into standalone Python script?

Tags: pyqgis

I want to create .qgis file from standalone Python script and I need to import pyqgis (qgis.core ). I tried commands:

`set PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\apps\qgis-ltr\python` and `set PATH=C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\bin;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;%PATH%`

and then in a Python console I tried

`import qgis.core`

and then I get error saying:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore'
```

Comment: possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/347265/49538

Comment: Please place the error in the Question body as text, so it is legible on all devices and free-text searchable